# How to get Nativescript-plugin-firebase admob SMART_BANNER height

Tags: firebase, nativescript

**Nativescript** Firebase plugin has *Admob* where you can use Smart Banner but we can't detect height of banner.
Who can i get banner height after it loads on different screen sizes?

```
  firebase.admob.showBanner({
    size: firebase.admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER, // see firebase.admob.AD_SIZE for all options
    margins: { // optional nr of device independent pixels from the top or bottom (don't set both)
      bottom: 10,
      top: -1
    },
    androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-9517346003011652/7749101329",
    iosBannerId: "ca-app-pub-9517346003011652/3985369721",
    testing: true, // when not running in production set this to true, Google doesn't like it any other way
    iosTestDeviceIds: [ //Android automatically adds the connected device as test device with testing:true, iOS does not
        "45d77bf513dfabc2949ba053da83c0c7b7e87715", // Eddy's iPhone 6s
        "fee4cf319a242eab4701543e4c16db89c722731f"  // Eddy's iPad Pro
    ],
    keywords: ["keyword1", "keyword2"], // add keywords for ad targeting
    onOpened: () => console.log("Ad opened"),
    onClicked: () => console.log("Ad clicked"),
    onLeftApplication: () => console.log("Ad left application")
  }).then(
      function () {
        console.log("AdMob banner showing");
      },
      function (errorMessage) {
        dialogs.alert({
          title: "AdMob error",
          message: errorMessage,
          okButtonText: "Hmmkay"
        });
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

**First we are getting screen size and then doing calculations with SMART_BANNER logic**

*Import this platform*

```
const platform = require("platform")
```

*Height divided by scale*

```
const screenHeightDp =platform.screen.mainScreen.heightPixels / platform.screen.mainScreen.scale;
```

*Doing calculations as smart banner works*

```
const BannerHeight = screenHeightDp > 720 ? 90 : screenHeightDp > 400 ? 50 : 32;
```

*This is our banner height*

```
console.log(BannerHeight);
```